# Google translator javascript not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello this is my code please reply me. 
this code working fine in all desktop browser but in mobile default browser not getting any output.

Thanks.

```
        <!-- Use CSS to replace link text with flag icons -->
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <ul class="translation-links">
          <li><a href="#" class="spanish" data-lang="Spanish">Spanish</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="german" data-lang="German">German</a></li>
        </ul>
        hello
        how are you ?
        <!-- Code provided by Google -->
        <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
          }
        </script>
        <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Flag click handler -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.translation-links a').click(function() {
              var lang = $(this).data('lang');
              var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
              if (!$frame.size()) {
                alert("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
                return false;
              }
              $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains('+lang+')').get(0).click();
              return false;
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: check if your mobile browser support javascript , if yes . check if it is enabled

Comment: ya mobile browser javascript enable. alert will come in function.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the similar issue when we wanted to have google translate for both browser and mobile responsiveness. How this script works is it loads the languages only once per page and it try to find the first element with `id` in the `<span>` tab it finds for `google_translate_element` and adds the languages.
We fixed this by using JS to remove the the HTML block added for desktop and with that now there is only one `google_translate_element` on the page and it shows the languages for mobile.

```
if($(document).width() < '768') {
    $('#block-googletranslator').remove();
}
```